# Local rails server don't work in production mode without deploy after rubber/capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, rubber

After install and configure Capistrano/rubber I can't run again my local rails server in production mode.

I got this error:

Unexpected error while processing request: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
    /home/doctorru/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gelf-1.4.0/lib/gelf/ruby_sender.rb:16:in `send' :

ruby_sender.rb 16:        @socket.send(datagram, 0, host, port)

Any help?